# Font-size acting differently locally vs. in production within a React-boostrap Navbar

Tags: css, reactjs, heroku, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have a website I am serving via Heroku that uses `<Navbar>` from React-bootstrap.

The issue is that the text of the website within the `<Navbar>` is showing as much larger in production than it does locally. Does anyone know what could possibly be causing this? The text not in `<Navbar>` is ok.

Note also that I have checked google chrome tools `font-size` property and it is telling me that the font size is the exact same both locally and in production, it just looks completely differently sized.

Comment: Are you able to confirm if you've checked the actual CSS `font-size` property? Perhaps you've viewed production site while browser was zoomed in. Another possibility is that someone could have altered some source code in the production server. Other than that, it could have been some overlooking in the deployment process. The font-size could have been altered recently and the changes have not been pushed to the release package

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have checked font-size and it says it is the same both locally and in production so that can't be it (have edited question with this info).  Also, this is a long-running issue and not because of a delay in things getting deployed.  I am the only one who pushes to the website so i don't think anyone has altered the production server source code.

Any other ideas?

Comment: They have the same computed `font-size`? Then the issue is another CSS property? I was going to suggest it could be a caching issue, or maybe some untracked code (e.g., gitignore), or perhaps some environment variables could be a factor, but since they have the same computed `font-size` then they should be the same size. At this point the only way I can help debug is if you can reproduce the issue via [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

The answer in the end was that I was zoomed in on chrome when looking at it via localhost but then when i went to look at it via the website the zoom was being reset. Zooming out solved the issue.

Comment: Incredible. Such a simple answer, but _exactly_ what happened to me. Thank you!